# c#, attempt to send message, if offline automatically sleep, reconnect, resend

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets, chat, send

The program currently works: you type in IP address, click connect, type in message, click send and the server receives and displays the message.

Client Code:

```
 public class Client
 {
    private const int DataSize = 65635;
    private byte[] data = new byte[DataSize];
    public Socket _socket;                      //the main socket
    public string strMsg;                       //sender's message string


    {
        get                                   
        {
            IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost");   
            IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[1];        
            return ipAddress.ToString();                 
        }
    }

    public EndPoint _epHost;   

    public bool Connect(string address)  
    {
        bool result = false; 
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(address)) return false;
        try
        {
            _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream,
                 ProtocolType.Tcp);
            IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(address);  
            IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 8040);
            _epHost = (EndPoint)ipEndPoint;
            _socket.Connect(_epHost);
            result = true; 
        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
        return result; 
    }

    // CITATION: Send() is a modified form of code by Jan Slama on his website
    // Link: http://www.csharp-examples.net/socket-send-receive/
    // License: "simple, straightforward examples suitable for copy and paste"

    public void Send(Data mailToBeSent, int offset, int timeout)
    {
        int startTickCount = Environment.TickCount;
        int sent = 0;  // how many bytes is already sent  

        data = mailToBeSent.ToByte();

            do
            {
                if (Environment.TickCount > startTickCount + timeout)
                {
                    data = null;
                    throw new Exception("Timeout.");
                }
                try
                {
                    sent += _socket.Send(data, offset + sent, 
                       data.Length - sent, SocketFlags.None);
                }
                catch (SocketException ex)
                {
                    if (ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.WouldBlock ||
                        ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.IOPending ||
                        ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.NoBufferSpaceAvailable)
                        // socket buffer is probably full, wait and try again
                        Thread.Sleep(30);
                    else
                        throw ex;  // any serious error occurs
                }
            }
            while (sent < data.Length);
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        if (_socket != null)
        {                
            _socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            _socket.Close();
        }
    }
}

public enum Command         //Commands for sender/receiver
{
    Message,                //Send a text message to the receiver
    Close,                  //Close
    Null,                   //No command
}
}
```

I'm trying to modify it so if the server/receiver is temporarily offline when the client/sender sends a message to it, the sender will automatically wait ten seconds, then try to reconnect and resend the message.

Right now I can do that by manually waiting, then re-clicking "connect" and then "send" but I'd like the sender to handle that on its own.

Code for the form:

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private Client _client;

    public Form1()          
    {
        InitializeComponent();                              
        _client = new Client();                                    
        Text = string.Format("Address: {0}", _client.IpAddress);    
        btnDisconnect.Enabled = false;                              
        tbMsg.Enabled = false;                                     
        btnSend.Enabled = false;                                   
    }

    private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   
    {
        if (_client.Connect(tbAddress.Text))    
        { 
            btnDisconnect.Enabled = true;       
            tbMsg.Enabled = true;               
            btnSend.Enabled = true;             
            tsLabel.Text = "Online";            
        }
    } 


    private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
       try
       {
          Data mailToBeSent = new Data();            
          mailToBeSent.cmdCommand = Command.Message;
          mailToBeSent.ipAddress = _client.IpAddress; 
          mailToBeSent.strMessage = tbMsg.Text;      
          _client.Send(mailToBeSent, 0, 1000);       
          tbMsg.Text = string.Empty;                         
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
          MessageBox.Show("Unable to deliver mail to receiver.", "Client", 
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }


    private void btnDisconnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        Data mailToBeSent = new Data();                    
        mailToBeSent.cmdCommand = Command.Close;           
        mailToBeSent.ipAddress = _client.IpAddress;        
        mailToBeSent.strMessage = string.Empty;            
        _client.Send(mailToBeSent, 0, 1000);               
        _client.Close();                                 
    }
}
```

First time posting here, I hope I did this right. Any advice is welcome.

Comment: Is the user allowed to click the button again and send another message, while you are still re-trying the previous message? If so, what message should take priority?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, extract the sending of message code in a new method returning bool:

```
private bool SendMessage()
{
   try
   {
      Data mailToBeSent = new Data();            
      mailToBeSent.cmdCommand = Command.Message;
      mailToBeSent.ipAddress = _client.IpAddress; 
      mailToBeSent.strMessage = tbMsg.Text;      
      _client.Send(mailToBeSent, 0, 1000);       
      tbMsg.Text = string.Empty;                         
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
       return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Then in your button click event you check if it succeeded and if not, wait and try again:

```
private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    int noOfRetries = 0;

    while(!SendMessage() && noOfRetries < 3) // Or whatever no of retries you want
    {
        noOfRetries++;
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }
}
```

Comment: This will block the UI for up to 30 seconds, at worst case.

Comment: I appreciate the information; didn't realize I was trying to do too much in one method. And while in other programs the 30 seconds of blocking might be an issue, in this case it should work fine.

Comment: Ok, if you find any of the given replies a satisfactory answer, you should mark it as the answer to your question, grey check mark. This will help others to see that the question got answered.

Answer (score 1):

The basic answer is to put message and destination in a queue.
and attempt to send, if it succeeds remove it from the queue.

Given you have potentially multiple destinations you need a queue for each one. `Dictionary<IP,List<Message>>` as a raw option.

Lots of potential optimisations at that point, and extensions such as send to a group.